# See authorized scopes with a google access token

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, oauth-2.0

Is It possible to determine the list of scopes that have been authorized (e.g, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"), given an access token?

I couldn't find any such endpoint in the documentation, but I'd be surprised if such functionality did not exist.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the OAuth 2.0 API for this. Try [tokeninfo in the API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo).